# OpenCV DFT_INVERSE different from Matlab's ifft

Tags: opencv, filter, fft, dft, ifft

I try to filter a signal using opencv's dft function. The way I try to this is taking the signal in time domain:

```
x = [0.0201920000000000 -0.0514940000000000 0.0222140000000000  0.0142460000000000  -0.00313500000000000    0.00270600000000000 0.0111770000000000  0.0233470000000000  -0.00162700000000000    -0.0306280000000000 0.0239410000000000  -0.0225840000000000 0.0281410000000000  0.0265510000000000  -0.0272180000000000 0.0223850000000000  -0.0366850000000000 0.000515000000000000    0.0213440000000000  -0.0107180000000000 -0.0222150000000000 -0.0888300000000000 -0.178814000000000  -0.0279280000000000 -0.144982000000000  -0.199606000000000  -0.225617000000000  -0.188347000000000  0.00196200000000000 0.0830530000000000  0.0716730000000000  0.0723950000000000]
```

Convert it to FOURIER domain using :

```
cv::dft(x, x_fft, cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT, 0);
```

Eliminate the unwanted frequencies:

```
for(int k=0; k<32;k++){
        if(k==0 || k>6 )
        {
            x_fft.ptr<float>(0)[2*k+0]=0;
            x_fft.ptr<float>(0)[2*k+1]=0;

        }
    }
```

Convert it back to time domain:

```
cv::dft(x_fft, x_filt, cv::DFT_INVERSE, 0);
```

In order to check my results I've compared them to Matlab. I took the same signal x, convert it to FOURIER using `x_mfft = fft(x);` The results are similar to the ones I get from opencv, excepting the fact that in opencv I only get the left side, while in matlab I get the symmetric values too.
After this I set to 0 in Matlab the values of `x_mfft(0) and x_mfft(8:32)` and now the signal look exactly the same except the fact that in Matlab they are in complex form, while in opencv they are separated, real part in one channel, imaginary part in the other.

**The problem** is that when I perform the inverse transform in matlab using `x_mfilt = ifft(x_mfft)` the results are completely different from what I get using opencv.
**Matlab**:

```
0.0126024108604191 + 0.0100628178150509i    0.00278762121814893 - 0.00615997579216921i  0.0116716145588075 - 0.0150834711251450i    0.0204808089882897 - 0.00937680194210788i   0.0187164132302469 - 0.000843687942567208i  0.0132322795522116 - 0.000108642129381095i  0.0140282455278201 - 0.00325620843335947i   0.0190436542174946 - 0.000556561558544529i  0.0182379867325824 + 0.00764390022568001i   0.00964801276734883 + 0.0107158342431018i   0.00405220362962359 + 0.00339496875258604i  0.0108096973356501 - 0.00476499376334313i   0.0236507440224628 - 0.000415067678294738i  0.0266197220512826 + 0.0154626911663024i    0.0142805873081583 + 0.0267004219364679i    0.000314527358302778 + 0.0215255889620223i  0.00173512964620177 + 0.00865151513638104i  0.0169666351363477 + 0.00836162056544561i   0.0255915540012784 + 0.0277878383595920i    0.0118710562486680 + 0.0506446948330055i    -0.0160165379892836 + 0.0553846122152651i   -0.0354343989166415 + 0.0406080858067314i   -0.0370261047451452 + 0.0261077990289579i   -0.0365120038155127 + 0.0268311542287801i   -0.0541841640123775 + 0.0312446266697320i   -0.0854132555297956 + 0.0125342802025550i   -0.0989182320365535 - 0.0377079727602073i   -0.0686133217915410 - 0.0925138855355046i   -0.00474198249025186 - 0.111728716441247i   0.0515933837210975 - 0.0814138940625859i    0.0663201317560107 - 0.0279433757588921i    0.0426055814586485 + 0.00821080477569232i
```

**OpenCV after cv::dft(x_fft, x_filt, cv::DFT_INVERSE, 0);**

Channel 1:

```
0.322008 -0.197121 -0.482671 -0.300055 -0.026996 -0.003475 -0.104199 -0.017810 0.244606 0.342909 0.108642 -0.152477 -0.013281 0.494806 0.854412 0.688818 0.276848 0.267571 0.889207 1.620622 1.772298 1.299452 0.835450 0.858602 0.999833 0.401098 -1.206658 -2.960446 -3.575316 -2.605239 -0.894184 0.262747
```

Channel 2:

```
0.403275 0.089205 0.373494 0.655387 0.598925 0.423432 0.448903 0.609397 0.583616 0.308737 0.129670 0.345907 0.756820 0.851827 0.456976 0.010063 0.055522 0.542928 0.818924 0.379870 -0.512527 -1.133893 -1.184826 -1.168379 -1.733893 -2.733226 -3.165383 -2.195622 -0.151738 1.650990 2.122242 1.363375
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't the results be similar? How can I check if the inverse transform in opencv is done correctly?

Later EDIT:
After struggling with the problems for a few hours now I've decided to plot the results from Matlab and OpenCV and to my surprise they were very much similar.

Imaginary parts
[image]

Real parts:
[image]

So obviously it's something about a SCALE factor. After dividing them element by element apparently this factor is 32 - the length of the signal. Can someone explain why this happens?
The obvious solution is to use `cv::dft(x_fft, x_filt, cv::DFT_INVERSE+cv::DFT_SCALE, 0);` so I guess this topic is answered but I'm still interested in why is it this way.

Comment: Attempting to "eliminate" frequencies by zeroing FFT bins can add a lot of noise to the result.  For a real result, the input to an IFFT needs to be conjugate symmetric, which means the high bins must mirror the imaginary part of the low bins, not be zeroed.

Comment: Why do you use `DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT` in `cv::dft(x, x_fft, cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT, 0);`. I am also having this problem. If you set DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flag, then you will get 2N length vector, and how do you do filtering on this vector. Without DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flag, then we get N length vector, and what is the difference on filtering.

Comment: to whom ever: the same problem occurs with ios accelerate framework and openCV and the scale difference there is 2. also the results are not organized the same - to my understanding (couldnt find docs) in openCV the first element is real part of the 0 frequency and then it is real img real img.. in accelerate framework it is real img real img all the way.. edit: ok the docs in openCV says it is real(0) real(1) img(1) real(2) img(2).. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#dft

Comment: ok and found the other docs.. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH202-15398 every thing is in the docs apparently (besides the scaling factor)

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard for scale factor used by all FFT libraries.  Some use none, some include a scale factor of 1/N, some 1/sqrt(N).  You have to test or look in the documentation for each particular library.